# Are civil remedies for landlord misconduct mutually exclusive?

Tags: united-kingdom, landlord, tenant, residential-lease, eviction

Following illegal eviction there may be civil damages under the [Protection from Eviction Act 1977](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/43/contents), but there may also be [Rent Repayment Orders](https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/housing_conditions/private_sector_enforcement/rent_repayment_orders) under the [Housing and Planning Act 2016](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/22/contents).

These are two examples of statutorily prescribed civil remedies but does one being pursued or obtained preclude others being separately claimed?

Comment: I don't know enough to offer an answer, but my basic understanding is that one cannot be awarded damages more that their loss(e.g. twice).

Comment: Yet RROs are not a form of damages as such, but rather just what they say on the tin, and a seemingly separate form of punitive penalty to disincentivise unscrupulous conduct.